# Adding the values in columns from different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

So I have these two dataframes:

```
df1:
          No_One
0  Team_1   1 
1  Team_2   1   
2  Team_3   1

df2:
          No_Two
0  Team_1   2
1  Team_2   2
2  Team_3   2
```

When I try to do:

```
df2['No_Two'] = df1['No_One'] + df2['No_Two']
print(df2)
```

I get:

```
df2:
          No_Two
0  Team_1   NaN
1  Team_2   NaN
2  Team_3   NaN
```

instead of

```
df2:
          No_Two
0  Team_1   3
1  Team_2   3
2  Team_3   3
```

Anyone know what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should work fine for the sample data. You should double check that your dataframes have identical index, including index's names.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you so much! I made sure to reset the index for both dataframes and it worked after that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df2['No_Two'] = list(map(lambda x:int(x[0])+int(x[1]) ,zip(df1['No_One'],df2['No_Two']))
print(df2)
```

Comment: I see this as a overkill for a simple series add task.